# unable to find weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime

Tags: java, server, weblogic

I am using a code from internet to get server's health status. weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime is used in that code and I am unable to find its jar. I am not using maven so please don't suggest maven. How can i get this jar

Comment: you should add the weblogic.jar lib in your application's classpath.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure your monitoring application is connecting to AdminServer as it's the only server in WebLogic domain that has domainruntime MBean server running. Then, try adding WebLogic client jar(i.e. wlthint3client.jar/wlfullclient.jar/wljmxclient.jar) to your monitoring application classpath.

More on WebLogic Stand-alone clients can be found on: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SACLT/basics.htm#SACLT125